# Multiple table query pagination and serach returing results of all tables but not from main table if they have nothing from other tables

Tags: php, mysql, search, pagination

Here’s what I have :

I have table 1 which is the `parties` table. It lists all the parties that are scheduled for the month.

I have 4 other tables, each contains the type of party favours that we use.

```
party_toys
party_drinks
party_foods
party_balloons
```

I need to query all parties that start this coming Saturday and list them back until the beginning of the year.

I have accomplished this.

What I need to do is figure out how to search but the party name from parties table and search all the party favours tables and list the results.

Still sorted this Saturday to the beginning of the year and  filter out parties which we do not have any favours.

Currently I can search only by party name from the parties table. I can’t figure out how to search all of them at the same time.

I also need to paginate all of these.

I currently have pagination working but it currently lists everything including the parties that have no favours assigned.

I am stuck. Does this make sense?

### Structure

For the parties table:

```
| party_id | parent_id | party_title | party_description | party_start | party finish |
```

For the party_drinks table:

```
| party_id | drink_id | drink_title | drink_notes |
```

For the party_foods table:

```
| party_id | food_id | food_title | food_notes |
```

For the party_toys table:

```
| party_id | toy_id | toy_title | toy_notes |
```

For the party_balloons table:

```
| party_id | balloon_id | ballon_title | balloon_notes |
```

Comment: Could you post your tables structure ?

Comment: I saved the structure above'

Comment: Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: writting a query which might do the work gimme a min :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT parties.*, party_toys.*, party_drinks.*, party_foods.*, party_balloons.*
FROM parties
INNER JOIN party_toys ON parties.id = party_toy.party_id 
INNER JOIN party_drinks ON parties.id = party_drinks.party_id 
INNER JOIN party_foods ON parties.id = party_foods.party_id 
INNER JOIN party_balloons ON parties.id = party_balloons.party_id 
WHERE parties.title LIKE "%Super party%"
OR party_toys.toy_title LIKE "%Super toy 9000%"
OR party_drinks.drink_title LIKE "%Tequila%"
OR party_foods.food_title LIKE "%Burger%"
```

This is going to select all the data from all the table so feel free to customize the infos you want to select. Then it's going to link all of them, and depending on the parameters you set on the WHERE it's going to return you the stuff you ask for.

Also for pagination you can do it using a get parameter from your url :

your_site.com/search.php?page=12

Get the page number before your query :

```
if( isset($_GET['page']) and is_int($_GET['page']) )
    $page = $_GET['page'];
else
    $page = 0;

$results_per_page = 20;
$offset = $page * $results_per_page;
```

Once you have your page number you just add this parameter at the end of your query

```
$query = "all the query i wrote above";
$auer .= " LIMIT ".$offset.", ".$results_per_page;
```

Comment: Just saw you didn't want to get the results if the parties don't have anything on the other tables so replace INNER JOIN by LEFT JOIN

Comment: Okay i just saw this so I will try it out and let you know

Comment: Okay so it mostly works but im getting double results of them. The pagination and search work great but results are doubled.

Comment: I had a mistake in my query I did not need to add distinct. thanks for your help! My query is not exactly like yours but it helped me get exactly what I needed! I really need to study mysql more sometimes I get really confused. I will post my query final query later i still have a few changes I need to make.

Comment: Hi again, So everything is working except it is not returning anything for parties.id in the results. I want to use that so I can link to another page that uses that id from this page. eg. mysite.com?parties=485 where 485 is the ID  and the page shows the details for just hat party. The page already exists. I'm just trying to get the ID without having to do another query. Is this possible?

Comment: You have to have in your query SELECT parties.party_id in order to be able to use it after